# Add Tax calculation in cart summary

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, tax

I would like to add a "tax amount" like shown in image below. I could find a setting for it so I presume it will have to be coded somewhere. Anyone?

[image: tax calculation]

It is basically the total amount of tax paid. Grand total (inc. tax) - Grand total (excl tax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use this configuration? :

System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Shopping Cart Display Settings:

+ Include Tax In Grand Total -> Yes

+ Display Full Tax Summary -> Yes

+ Display Zero Tax Subtotal -> Yes